# How to integrate this : $ \int \cot(5x) \tan(2x) \mathrm{d}x$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

Methods to integrate this integral:

$$\int \cot(5x) \tan(2x) \mathrm{d}x$$

I have tried several methods, step by step, and they have led to invalid results. Helpful hints or processes are welcome.

I did this further :

$$ \cot(5x) = \frac{1}{\tan(2x+ 3x)}$$
$$= \frac{1}{\frac{\tan 2x +\tan 3x}{1-\tan 2x\tan 3x}}$$

Simplifying it further by breaking $\tan(3x) = \tan(2x +x)$  again we get 
$$= \frac{1-\tan^2 x -2\tan x \tan 2x}{2\tan 2x -\tan^2 2x . \tan x +\tan x}$$

now the integral is $$ = \frac{1-\tan^2 x -2\tan x \tan 2x}{2\tan 2x -\tan^2 2x . \tan x +\tan x} \tan 2x $$

Can we do something with this further thanks..

Comment: Not a [beautiful answer](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+of+cot%285x%29tan%282x%29).

Comment: You can do the change of variable $u=\tan(x)$, exploiting the fact that $\tan(a+b)=(\tan(a)+\tan(b))/(1-\tan(a)\tan(b))$. This should give you a (messy) algebraic fraction in $u$.

Comment: @TerranDrop What about $\cot(5x)$? Do you suggest writing it as $\displaystyle \frac{1}{\tan(x+x+x+x+x)}$?

Comment: Well, I guess $\tan(5x)=\tan(2x+2x+x)$ would be quicker to compute, but yeah. Maybe there is a better way to calculate the integral, but given the expression from Wolfram, things should get messy anyways.

Comment: If we write $\cot(5x)$ as $\displaystyle\frac{\cos 5x}{\sin 5x}$ and use the Chebychev polynomials it'll be faster.

Comment: @Ishu $dx$ or $\mathrm{d}x$ is a matter of style; it's a personal choice.

Comment: You can rewrite the integrand as $\frac{\sin{7x} -\sin{3x}}{\sin{7x}+\sin{3x}}$, but that also leads to no easy route

Comment: the integral looks ugly

Answer (score 4):

Letting $\tan x=z$, the integral can be rewritten as $$I=\int \frac{2z(1-10z^2+5z^4)}{(1-z^4)(5z-10z^3+z^5)}dz\\=2\int\frac{1-10z^2+5z^4}{(1-z^4)(5-10z^2+z^4)}dz\\=2\int \frac{1}{1-z^4}dz-8\int \frac{1}{5-10z^2+z^4}dz\\=2J-8K$$ where $J$ can be easily evaluated. As for $K$, it can be written as $$\int \frac{1}{(z^2-5-2\sqrt{5})(z^2-5+2\sqrt{5})}dz$$ which can then be evaluated without much effort. I admit that the final expressions will be ugly, but the evaluation process is straightforward.

Comment: Maybe you could add what identity of $\cot 5x$ did you use.

Comment: @metacompactness, I just used the usual formula for $\tan 5x$ namely $\tan 5x=\frac{5\tan x-10\tan^3x+\tan^5x}{1-10\tan^25x+5\tan^4x}$

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\frac{\tan 2x}{\tan x}=\frac{1+\cos 2x}{\cos 2x}$ and
$\frac{\cot 5x }{ \cot x }=\frac{2\cos4x-2\cos2x+1}{2\cos4x+2\cos2x+1}
$
to get
$$\cot(5x) \tan(2x)
=\frac{1+\cos2x}{\cos2x}-\frac{4(1+\cos2x)}{4\cos^2 2x+2\cos2x-1}$$
Then
$$I=\int \cot5x \tan2x\ dx=I_1+I_2
$$
where
\begin{align}I_1=&\int\frac{1+\cos2x}{\cos2x}dx= x+\frac12\tanh^{-1}(\sin2x)\\
I_2=&\int\frac{1+\cos2x}{\cos^2 2x+\frac12\cos2x-\frac14}dx\\
=&\ \frac1{\sqrt{5(5+2\sqrt5})}\ln\frac{\tan x -\sqrt{5+2\sqrt5} }{\tan x +\sqrt{5+2\sqrt5} }
-\frac1{\sqrt{5(5-2\sqrt5})}\ln\frac{\tan x -\sqrt{5-2\sqrt5} }{\tan x +\sqrt{5-2\sqrt5} }
\end{align}
A similar, yet simpler, integral reads
\begin{align}
&\int \cot3x\tan 2x\ dx \\
= &\int (1+\cos2x)\left(-\frac1{\cos2x}+\frac4{2\cos2x+1}\right)dx\\
=&\ -x-\frac12\tanh^{-1}(\sin2x)+\frac2{\sqrt3}\ln\frac{\tan x+\sqrt3}{\tan x-\sqrt3}
\end{align}